# Switch USB port to power only

Tags: usb

I have an overly "smart" camera connected to my 16.04 box over USB which recognizes when it is plugged into a computer and does not record. I need a way to switch the USB port from data to power only. Is this something I can do with some apt package or by fiddling with /sys/bus/usb?

Comment: try [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148664/control-usb-connection-power-only-charge) solution